# How to find ComboBox value in this situation?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I have the following XAML code:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbColors">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

and .cs code:

```
public ComboBoxDataBindingSample()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     cmbColors.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
}
```

What is a way I could set the current combobox value displayed to "Black" without using a for loop to find the index of it?

Comment: Please keep in mind this combobox contains a rectangle and a textblock. Doing cmbColors.SelectedItem = "Black" ; will not set the selected item to black.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this :

```
cmbColors.SelectedItem = "Black" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find programmaticaly it by using the following code.

```
int index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(a);
```

To get the item itself, write:

```
comboBox1.Items[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do via code

```
cmbColors.SelectedValue = "Black";
```